# windows.open() refuses to open google

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Simply put, if I try to open https://www.google.com via a button click and windows.open() function, it always gives me the "www.google.com refused to connect." screen.

If I try too many times, Edge end up blocking google entirely and I have to restart the browser, after which google works fine when searching from the address bar or google's home page.  This is custom code I'm adding to a newtab extension.

```js
function mySearch() {
  var URL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";
  var searchBx = document.getElementById("searchBx").value;

  window.open(URL.concat(searchBx), '_self');
}
```

```html
<div class="searchBx">
  <input type="text" name="" class="query" id="searchBx" value="">
</div>
<div class="button">
  <button class="searchBtn" onclick="mySearch()">Google Search</button>
</div>
```

I was expecting it to open a google page with the search parameters from what I entered into the input box I added to the new tab screen.

Comment: You aren't URL-encoding your querystring.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You have the question tagged `google-chrome-extensdion`, maybe the problem is related to your manifest.

Comment: Also, **you don't need any JavaScript at all** for this - you can use a `<form target="_blank" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">` with an `<input type="search" name="q" />` and `<button type="submit">Go</button>` and that's it.

Comment: I tried the form method and it's doing the same thing.  I even turned off all extensions on Edge and it still tells me google.com is blocked, ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE